# Lowering the brightness of the camera flash

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-duos, camera-flash

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Duos (GT-S7562L).

The camera is good, but its flash is so strong that after the photo we have to wait for 1 or 2 minutes to our eyes be able to see all clearly - it is like to when you see the sun light directly.

So I would like to change flash brightness in some way: hardware or software.

The easier but ugliest hardware way is to use a semi-transparent sticker in front of lens.

Do you know any way to change flash brightness entering some hidden settings (common settings do not have that option) or using another settings app or camera app? The phone is not rooted, but I accept solutions in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was asked over at StackOverflow [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970188/can-i-change-the-led-intensity-of-an-android-device)

Basically, the answer is No. The OS is limited to pretty much just FLASH_ON and FLASH_OFF. Though I have seen some flashlight/torch apps that have a 'turbo' mode that makes the LED even brighter (but that's not what you want and these types of apps usually require ROOT access).

Another workaround is to remove the back cover, put a small piece of tissue paper over the LED (make sure the paper is still big enough to be held in place with the back-cover back on) and put the cover back on.

Answer (score -1):

yes of course you can lower the intensity -- you just have to have the flash OFF mmore than on. 
http://www.electronicproducts.com/Optoelectronics/LEDs/LED_101_How_do_dimmable_LEDs_work.aspx

Comment: This is a good start, but it needs more detail to be useful. What exactly would you do to apply this principle to your smartphone?